# jQuery css3 attribute not working

Tags: jquery, css

```
var containerHeight = $(".item").height();

    $(".word-game .nWord").css({
        "-webkit-transform" : "translate(0, " + containerHeight + ")"
    });
```

here is my code, but it doesn't work. i'm really tired.

Comment: I wanted to put in some effort to help you out but I got tired.

Comment: it still doesn't work :S

Comment: A Fiddle would be helpful + are you using a browser that supports CSS3?

Comment: yes, i use chrome latest version. thanks for your comment.

Comment: I'll give you a half-answer to your half-question. `translate()` doesn't take integers as arguments.

Comment: try with line: console.log( $(".word-game .nWord").length );    <- If  that returns a value greater 0, then your jQuery selector is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `px` or `%` to your current function since `translate` doesn't know what to do with a plain integer.

```
var containerHeight = $(".item").height();

$(".word-game .nWord").css({
    "transform" : "translate(0,"+containerHeight+"px)"
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nuuLjhL0/

Comment: thank you, i try this before your comment but it wasn't work. i try now again and perfect.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var containerHeight = $(".item").height();
   $(".word-game .nWord").css({
     "-webkit-transform":"translate(0px,"+containerHeight+"px)"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Making sure it works in all browsers :)

```
            "-webkit-transform": "translate(0,"+containerHeight+"px)",
            "-moz-transform": "translate(0,"+containerHeight+"px)",
            "-ms-transform":"translate(0,"+containerHeight+"px)",
            "-o-transform":"translate(0,"+containerHeight+"px)",
            "transform": "translate(0,"+containerHeight+"px)"
```